# Shared client & server modules with angularjs and pongular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, dependency-injection, coffeescript

Looking for advice from javascript experts -- is there a better (terser? safer?) way to do this?

I'm writing modules that work with the DI syntax for both angularjs (client-side) and pongular (server-side).

```
di = (typeof window!='undefined') && window.angular || require('pongular').pongular
di.module 'thecrewApp'

.factory 'fbRoot', ['fbUrl', 'Firebase', (fbUrl, Firebase)-> new Firebase(fbUrl)]
```

My client-side angular app can use this injectable, as can my server-side node app.  I do this for a bunch of injectables that are used on both client and server.

Is there a better way to express this?  The first line, where I pick which DI engine to use based on typeof window... feels hacky.

Comment: Perhaps adding function require() { return angular; } to your browser-side code...?

Comment: Also, look into using ES6, with babel or traceur for the front-end.

Comment: defining require is a great tip, suggest it as an answer, awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of some possible solutions:

- Include in the shared files only the array of dependencies and the function call (e.g. `module('moduleName').factory(["$http", function($http) { ... }]);`), and use a preprocessor to wrap the file with `angular.` or `pongular.`
- Define angular or pongular globally in one environment. Or, define a function globally that returns the proper reference, e.g.

  ```
  // in the browser
  function require() { return angular; }
  ```

Then your require code will work across environments.

- Look into using ES6 modules.